# Does the oxygen level in the air drop at night or in the early morning?

Tags: medical-science, environmental-health

There is a pseudoclaim that the oxygen level in the air drops at night and in the early morning (before dawn), and that the change is of sufficient magnitude to influence health.

Comment: Welcome to skeptics.se. Questions on this site should be about [notable claims](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation). We need a reference to some notable person who has claimed this is true, preferably online or on print. "I have heard" is not sufficient.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. I searched but couldn't find a notable claim.

Comment: You have changed the wording from "I have heard" to "there is a pseudoclaim" but you have still not provided references to show that anyone besides you is actually making this claim. That's what will be required in order to reopen this question.

Comment: Likely to be difficult to answer this one with a reference, but straightforward to apply common sense.  The atmosphere is about 21% oxygen, the fluxes required to make a serious dent in that on a daily basis would be huge and we would have noticed the mechanism in action.  I suspect this is due to the fact that plants continually respire, but don't photosynthesise at night, so at night they take up more O2 than they release.  This might be measurable indoors, but won't have a significant effect outdoors.  Common sense also suggests that if this had been going on for a long time...

Comment: ...then humans might just have developed evolutionary adaptions to it.  However this site doesn't implement scientific skepticism, which would include individual research and logic based answers.